# i made a "highlight" class in html, and when I use it on my paragraph, the paragraph's margin changes

Tags: html, css, class, external

I have just started html 3 weeks ago, and when I started I learned inline style instead of the preferred external style, but I now understand external. Forgive me if I use incorrect terms for certain actions. I have created a "highlight" class in my style tag and it works by changing the background color yellow. When I assign class to the my paragraph tag, the margins of the paragraph change.

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=http://www.derekowens.com/ch06.css>

<h1>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</h1>
<p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
<p>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </p>
<p class="highlight">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the stylesheet you're including (`http://www.derekowens.com/ch06.css`) already has a `.highlight` class and it restricts the width of the element it's applied to.

The following rule is defined in `ch06.css`:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
}
```

To fix this override the value of the `width` property in your own `.highlight` class, something like `initial`. You might also want to change the name of your highlight class so it's not inheriting from an existing class, i.e. `.hl`.

**Note:** the `ch06.css` file also sets some awkward styles for `p`.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I can't change the styling on the link because it's the teacher's. Atleast I know it's not a problem.

Comment: Updated answer to include how to override `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's not changing the margin - the yellow background will fill the full width of the available space, because `<p>` is a block level element.

Try this:

```
<p>Test <span class="highlight">test test</span> test.</p>
```

This should work, because `span` is an inline element.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 0):

You have `.highlight { width: 200px; }` in ch06.css. Remove that if you don't want to limit the paragraph's width.